# install4j distributable component name

Tags: install4j

Right now if you have distributed components the files take the media file name pattern (for example if the executable is named Test_windows_0_1.exe the files will have the name Test_windows_0_1.component_id.dat)

Is there any way to set a specific name for each of the distributable components?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've added this to our issue tracker.